How to add custom option in the right click menu (Windows 11)
I want to add an option in the menu when right clicking on any file (Windows 11).
I already changed the menu appearance so it looks like Windows 10's menu and I already added an option that opens Powershell and prints "Hello World".  I went in the registry editor to do that.
right click menu exemple
reg edit
What I would like to know is what to change in the registry editor so my TestHelloWorld option appears every time I click on any type of file, a little like "Properties" or "Open" would show up in any case.

This question belongs on [su], as it is a general operating system question. SO is strictly for questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool (IDE, compiler, etc.).
